# Due to Content-Security-Policy it is not displaying CSS and JS on both storefront and admin after my magento 2.4.5 installation using docker

Tags: magento2.4.5, cloud-docker

[image: not loading css and js due to Content-Security-Policy in magento]
Due to Content-Security-Policy  it is not displaying CSS and JS on both storefront and admin after my magento 2.4.5 installation using docker.

i try deleting var and inside pub/static except .htaccess i deleted all file after i tried
static content deploy, and also insering a value o for core_confi_data table, after i tried changing symlinks to copy in etc/di.xml,after that i add [Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch] in .htaccess but all are not working.